# Node Spawn preserve color

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I have the following script:

```
const child = spawn('log-processor', [], {shell: true});
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stdin.setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');

const write = (line) => {
  child.stdin.write(`${line}\n');
}
```

Normally, using `echo '...' | log-processor` the log is printed with colors. However, using the script above, the color is not preserved.

How can I preserve the log color `log-processor` creates?

Comment: are the backticks escaping the color? do you need them?

Comment: `write(line + '\n')` also has no color. `line` here is a just a regular string. It does not have color. `log-processor` output is stringified, and I'm assuming the color loss i happening on `pipe(process.stdout);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any color because the command you're trying to execute, like most CLIs, don't output any color when they aren't run inside a TTY environment.
In order to get a more authentic output, you need to create a pseudo-terminal (PTY). Sadly this isn't natively possible from node.
I was stuck with this problem, and didn't want to use `node-pty`, which is a hassle to install (node-gyp nightmares) so [I made this](https://github.com/CyriacBr/get-pty-output).
This'll solve your problem, cheer!